# How to execute query N times in H2 database?

Tags: h2

I have a query that inserts data to H2 database.

```sql
INSERT INTO USER_TABLE(USER_ID)
VALUES(RANDOM_UUID())
```

I need to generate 1000 rows for testing, how can I do it for **H2** ? Is there something like `GO 1000` in MSSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SYSTEM_RANGE`](https://h2database.com/html/systemtables.html#range_table) to generate the necessary number of rows in the query and use this query as a source for `INSERT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO USER_TABLE(USER_ID) SELECT RANDOM_UUID() FROM SYSTEM_RANGE(1, 1000);
```